# Using Mirth Connect Destination Mappings for AWS Access Key Id results in Error

Tags: mirth

We use vault to store our credentials, I've successfully grabbed S3 Access key ID and Secret Access key using the vault API, and used channelMap.put to create mappings: ${access_key} and ${secret_key}.

[aws_s3_file_writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XNZ1.png)

However when I use these in the S3 file writer I get the error:

"The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

I know the Access Key Id is valid, it works if I plug it in directly in the S3 file writer destination.

I'd appreciate any help on this.  thank you.

UPDATE: I had to convert the results to a string, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the variable to a higher map. You can use `globalChannelMap`, `globalMap` or `configurationMap`. I would use this last one since it can store password not in plain text mode. You are currently using a `channelMap`, it scope is only applied to the current message while it is traveling through the channel.

You can check more about variable maps and their scopes in [Mirth User guide](https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/Files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-311-user-guide.pdf), Section Variable Maps, page 393. I think that part of the manual is really important to understand.

Comment: The issue was that the credentials were coming from vault, which in turn sends the information to AWS.  BUT, we were using the credentials before vault could get the credentials to AWS, which is why we got the 'does not exist...' error.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment, it was a race condition between Vault, Mirth and AWS.